# How to get value of sibling select on btn click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, siblings

I want to get the value of selected option on button click. 
Problem is that I have several groups of button and select. So, I have to use sibling somehow, but I cant figure out how to.....

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="category in categories"> 
<div id="kkal-type" class="form-options">
     <select name="{{cats[$index]}}" id="{{cats[$index]}}">
        <option value="0" >--Не выбрано--</option>

        <option ng-repeat="food in category.foods" ng-show="food.available" value="{{food.cost}}">{{food.name+" - "+food.cost+"тг"}}</option>

     </select> 
     <input type="button" value="ВЫБРАТЬ" class="choose-btn orange filled" ng-click="update(this)"/ >    
</div>
```

```
$scope.update = function(btn) {
    console.log(  $(btn).siblings('select').val());  
};
```

But this doesnt work. 
Who knows how to get this working?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

just use `ng-model` on select and pass that value to `ng-click` function

```
 <select name="{{cats[$index]}}" id="{{cats[$index]}}" ng-model="selectedItem">

 <input type="button" value="ВЫБРАТЬ" class="choose-btn orange filled" ng-click="update(selectedItem)"/ >    

 $scope.update = function(selectedItem) {
    console.log( selectedItem);  
 };
```

on the side note, use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`

```
<select name="{{cats[$index]}}" id="{{cats[$index]}}" ng-options="food.cost as food.name for food in category.foods" ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option value="0" >--Не выбрано--</option> 
 </select
```

> 

Comment: This is the Angular way of doing it. There is no need to go ask a control what its value is since that should already be stored in the `$scope`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer --`ng-model` is the AngularJS way -- no need for any jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Just navigate to the parent: `$.parent()` and then search downwards: `$.find("select")`.

You can also use the `$.closest()` method, this will look in the tree and find the closest element that suits your selector, which is what you need:

```
$scope.update = function(btn) {
    console.log(  $(btn).closest('select').val());  
};
```